# how to get/control the elements of the popup of a google chrome extension using puppeter?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I know that I can modify the extension code, but I want to do some steps on the chrome extension popup.
So, if I have access to the elements of the HTML of the popup of the google chrome extension ( as I have on pages with puppeteer ) I could control the chrome extension.

Comment: Here is a [documentation of chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) in which you can refer to start with your dev. Also for puppeteer, you can check this [github post](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Comment: Puppeteers documentation doesn't have any information about how to send messages or control a chrome extension (access of the html popup of the chrome extension). Just specify how to load one.